# Custom of two people not clothing someone together

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, minhag, clothing, mourning-aveilus

Probably a common occurrence is when putting clothes on a baby, both parents will try to do it together to make it easier (one puts on the shirt, one puts on the pants, etc.). Someone recently told me that there's a custom not to do this, as it resembles taking care of the deceased (apparently two people clothe/unclothe the deceased together?). I guess this would be similar to avoiding passing bread by hand, which I understand is normally done at a *shiva* meal.

Is this a real custom? Is it sourced in any *halacha sefarim*? Is it commonly followed? I never heard of it, and I thought it was just superstition, but then someone else told me that they asked a Chabad Rabbi who said he is careful not to do this, but that he doesn't know the source. So I suppose one group of Jews does follow this...

Comment: Rav Shlomo Aviner says that it is permitted

Comment: @sam is that recorded anywhere? What is his reasoning? Because there's no reason for it to be forbidden? Is he coming to deny this minhag?